# Not able to get ip of stub

Tags: java, rmi

I have a java RMI server which exports itself with UnicastRemoteObject.export. Is there a way to find out the IP address that was embedded in the server stub? and how can i change this ip ?

Comment: Any code you could share?

Comment: @user1945532 What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can control it *before* exporting, via the 'java.rmi.server.hostname' property, and when you get the stub at the client you can *see* it via the toString() method, but there's no way to change it after the stub is created, and even if there was, the resulting stub probably wouldn't work anyway.

I'm wondering why you think you need to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to use third variant of `UnicastRemoteObject.export` method whitch is

```
exportObject(Remote obj, int port, RMIClientSocketFactory csf, RMIServerSocketFactory ssf)
```

here you would have to implement and provide own socket factories where you could specify all socket parameters you would need.

Comment: @user1945532 do you understand the solution I have described above?

Comment: no cause of i am sending only remote object. then how it can send other param

Comment: use the `export` method i show above with socket factories. From there you can set IP addresses.

Comment: where i have to set the ip address.

Comment: in socket factories you will provide to `exportObject` method

Comment: where i will get RMIClientSocketFactory,RMIServerSocketFactory object ?

Comment: You need to implement the them.

Comment: so from where stub is registering the IP SynchronousPresenceServiceImpl_Stub[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[172.16.230.75:52718]

Comment: Default implementation? Check the java sources and you will know

Comment: So how does he get the socket factory from the stub? How does this answer the question?